# AR Foundation: Detect when the user has closed the camera with his hand

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am working on an AR application in Unity using the AR Foundation (AR Core + AR Kit). It is necessary to determine the moment when the user closed the camera with his hand in order to perform a reset position action.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In ARKit, tracking state is set to limited when there is not enough features. In ARFoundation, I think it is set to **ARSessionState.SessionInitialized**. If you close the camera with your hand, device cannot be determine its current position with fewer features. So session state cannot be "SessionTracking". You can use this states if you like.